# Having trouble with EE3 and NavEE

Tags: ee3, navigation, navee

I am using EE 3.2.1 and NavEE 3.1.0

I am having trouble with the `{is_selected}` parameter and the home page displaying in breadcrumbs.

I have the following for my nav:

```
<!-- Navigation 
================================================== --> 
<nav id="navigation" class="style-1"> 
    <div class="left-corner"> 
        <div class="right-corner"> 
            <ul class="menu" id="responsive"> 
                {exp:navee:custom 
                    nav_title='primary' 
                    wrap_type='none' 
                } 
                    <li><a href="{link}" {if '{is_selected}' == TRUE}id="current"{/if}><i class="halflings white {custom}"> {text} 
{/exp:navee:custom} 
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have also tried:

```
{if is_selected}id="current"{/if}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Also the home page/link is not displaying in `{custom_crumbs}` and `{last_anchor}` is not working in the following:

```
<nav id="breadcrumbs"> 
    <ul> 
        <li>You are here:</li> 
        {exp:navee:custom_crumbs 
            wrap_type="none" 
            no_last_anchor="true" 
        } 
            <li><a href="{link}">{text}</a></li> 
        {/exp:navee:custom_crumbs} 
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an issue with NavEE. (See email)

> Hey Brian,
>
> Didn't need to FTP in or anything - just needed to look at your setup.
>   I've been able to recreate the bug and it was a combination of the
>   Prefix with Site URL + the selected state regex stuff. I simplified
>   the way I add those prefixes, but forgot to take that into account
>   when cleaning the URI for comparison.
>
> Can you give this version a try and let me know if it works for you?
>   Don't forget you need to add back in the {if is_selected} stuff and/or
>   just use the {class} variable.
>
> MW

Like always, Michael was great to get to the issue quickly and respond with a provided solution. All is well in the world again now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!-- Navigation 
================================================== --> 
<nav id="navigation" class="style-1"> 
    <div class="left-corner"> 
        <div class="right-corner"> 
            <ul class="menu" id="responsive"> 
                {exp:navee:custom 
                    nav_title="primary" 
                    wrap_type="none"
                    selected_class="current"
                } 
                    <li><a href="{link}" {if class}id="{class}"{/if}><i class="halflings white {custom}"> {text} 
                {/exp:navee:custom} 
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```